# lookup file name in sql and rename file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use a Powershell script to use the account number in a file name and re-name with the ID number from a sql database. Below is the code I am using to attempt this and I am not getting the results I need. Please let me now if you have any suggestion or advise in getting this to work.

Thanks!!

File name = 111119999.docx

Table =

ID            AccountNumber

5555       111119999

```
## Select Data from Database

function Select-Info($CliRef) 
   {
    $conn = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $connstring = “provider=sqloledb;data source=[vmsvr039];initial catalog=[crs5_oltp];integrated security=SSPI”    
    $conn.connectionstring = $connstring

    $conn.open()
    $query = “Select convert(varchar,cnsmr_accnt_idntfr_agncy_id) as ID FROM cnsmr_accnt WHERE cnsmr_accnt_crdtr_rfrnc_id_txt = '$CliRef'”
    $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sql,$conn)
    $cmd.connection = $conn
    $cmd.commandtext = $query
    $result = $cmd.executenonquery()
    $conn.close()

    return $query
    }

## Return ID from Database

function Return-Info($CliRef)
   {
    $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $conn.ConnectionString = "Server=vmsvr039;Database=crs5_oltp;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    $conn.Open()
    $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $cmd.commandtext = “Select convert(varchar,cnsmr_accnt_idntfr_agncy_id) as ID FROM cnsmr_accnt WHERE cnsmr_accnt_crdtr_rfrnc_id_txt = '$CliRef'”
    $cmd.connection = $conn
    $result = $cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    $conn.close()   

    return $result
    }

 ## Collect the file names

 $FiNms = Get-ChildItem H:\ps\test -Name

 ## Loop through each file name

 foreach ($FiNm in $FiNms)
     {

 ## Variable for current File path
    $file = “H:\ps\test\” + $FiNm

 ##  Variable for new File path
    $newFile = “H:\ps\renamed\” + $FiNm

 $ID = Return-Info $CliRef
 $ID = $ID + “.docx”
 Copy-Item $file -Destination $newFile
 Rename-Item $file $ID -force
     }
```

Comment: "I am not getting the results I need" - describe what you ARE getting and maybe someone will try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

By changing the $ID = Return-Info $CliRef to $ID = Return-Info $FiNm I was able to get this to work. The file name will also need to have the ".docx" removed.

```
## Return ID from Database
 function Return-Info($CliRef)
{

$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = "Server=vmsvr039;Database=crs5_oltp;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
$conn.Open()
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$cmd.commandtext = “Select convert(varchar,cnsmr_accnt_idntfr_agncy_id) as ID FROM cnsmr_accnt WHERE cnsmr_accnt_crdtr_rfrnc_id_txt = '$CliRef'”
$cmd.connection = $conn
$result = $cmd.ExecuteScalar()
$conn.close()  

return $result

}

 ## Collect the image names
 $FiNms = Get-ChildItem H:\ps\test -Name

 ## Loop through each Image name
 foreach ($FiNm in $FiNms)

{

 ## Variable for current File path
 $file = “H:\ps\test\” + $FiNm
 ##  Variable for new File path
 $newFile = “H:\ps\renamed\” + $FiNm

$ID = Return-Info $FiNm

$ID = $ID + “.docx”

Copy-Item $file -Destination $newFile

Rename-Item $file $ID -force

}
```

Comment: please use the Code Sample formatting in the future to make it easier to read when pasting a script or other code - this is the {} symbol in the menu above where you type a question/answer